# Setting GKE node pool to auto_upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a kubernetes cluster on GKE. I'd like to enable `auto_upgrade` for each node pool and I'd like to do this in terraform. I'm not sure how.

The node pools are defined with terraform like this

```
module "main-gke-cluster" {
  source = "../modules/gke-cluster"

  cluster_name = local.stage_main_cluster_name
  // SNIP...

  node_pools = {

    default-pool = {
      machine_type = "e2-standard-2"
      image_type = "UBUNTU"
      initial_node_count = 1
      min_nodes = 0
      max_nodes = 10
      preemptible = true
      node_locations = [
        "europe-west4-a"
      ]
      labels = {}
      taints = []
      oauth_scopes = local.default_pool_scopes
      has_gpu = false
    }
```

I attempted to set `auto_upgrade` on the node pool like so

```
module "main-gke-cluster" {
  source = "../modules/gke-cluster"

  cluster_name = local.stage_main_cluster_name
  // SNIP...

  node_pools = {

    default-pool = {
      machine_type = "e2-standard-2"
      image_type = "UBUNTU"
      initial_node_count = 1
      min_nodes = 0
      max_nodes = 10
      auto_upgrade = true
      preemptible = true
      node_locations = [
        "europe-west4-a"
      ]
      labels = {}
      taints = []
      oauth_scopes = local.default_pool_scopes
      has_gpu = false
    }
```

ie I added an `auto_upgrade` parameter.

This appears to have no effect on the `terraform plan`.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: What are the contents of the module `main-gke-cluster`? Does it expect an `auto_upgrade` parameter?

Comment: Are you using the Jetstack gke-cluster module?  It looks like you are.  I believe that's been deprecated in favor of https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine

Comment: I don't see the term Jetstack anywhere in the terraform config. I might be using that, but not sure. How can I tell?

Comment: This is what I see in the `modules.json` file.


```
{"Modules":[{"Key":"main-gke-cluster","Source":"../modules/gke-cluster","Dir":"../modules/gke-cluster"},{"Key":"stage_main_nvidia_driver","Source":"../modules/nvidia-driver-installer","Dir":"../modules/nvidia-driver-installer"},{"Key":"vpn-server","Source":"../modules/vpn-server","Dir":"../modules/vpn-server"},{"Key":"","Source":"","Dir":"."},{"Key":"dev-infra-gke-cluster","Source":"../modules/gke-cluster","Dir":"../modules/gke-cluster"},{"Key":"kafka","Source":"../modules/kafka","Dir":"../modules/kafka"}]}
```

Comment: There may be another set of Terraform files organized as a [module](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules), located at the relative path `../modules/gke-cluster`. Just adding `auto_upgrade` won't do anything if the Terraform module at this location doesn't expect it, you will need to modify that module first. What are the contents of this module?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts
You are so right. I found this in the `../modules/gke-cluster` location

  management {
    auto_repair = false
    auto_upgrade = false
  }

I think I get how to fix this now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using the [Jetstack gke-module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/jetstack/gke-cluster/google/latest?tab=inputs), then by default node pools will be set to use auto-upgrade.  But if you want to explicitly enable auto-upgrade, then I believe the parameter you want to use is "[management_auto_upgrade](https://github.com/jetstack/terraform-google-gke-cluster/blob/master/variables.tf#L78)".

Comment: Hmmm. I tried adding that parameter, but it appears to be unrecognized.

```
    default-pool = {
      machine_type = "e2-standard-2"
      image_type = "UBUNTU"
      initial_node_count = 1
      min_nodes = 0
      max_nodes = 10
      management_auto_upgrade = true
```

I saw no change in the terraform plan. 

I'm pretty sure my node pools are not set to auto-upgrade currently, as the GKE console shows the setting disabled.

Comment: I guess you were using a custom module and not the Jetstack one.